# Configure the language of puppeteer's chromium browser or using Apify proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, cheerio, apify

I want to scrape a website with french result , the website support many languages . How can I do that , is it better to configure puppeteer Crawler launch options  in args as in puppeter like that :

```js
const pptr = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
const browser = await pptr.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
        '--lang=fr' 
    ] });
    
    
})();
```

in Apify , as I understand will be as that :

```js
const Apify = require("apify");

(async () => {
const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer({
    headless: false,
    args: [
        '--lang=fr' 
    ] });
    
    
})();
```

And how can I use Apify Proxies for this case .

Comment: I suggest you to read the documentation on Getting started https://docs.apify.com/actors/quick-start

Comment: I read it , but I didn't yet find a clear answer to my question. Can you be precise and give me the exact part that answer my question ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any magic option on the browser. The website will figure your language depending on your IP location or cookies you set up. If you are on the page, you can check what cookies are set for the specific language (if the website has this option) and then [set them up for your scraper](https://help.apify.com/en/articles/1444249-log-in-to-website-by-transferring-cookies-from-web-browser).

Or you can use localized proxies to get the correct IP address.

Comment: Not every websites figure your language using your IP